# Summation Notation With Variable Endpoint

Tags: integration, summation, notation

I have this equation:

$\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \cfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$

The above is equivalent to: 
$\cfrac{1}{n(n+1)} | n=(k+1)$
 Why is this true? Is it the result of integration? If so can someone show the work for it?

Comment: Do you know partial fractions, or what it means for a series to telescope?

Comment: Yeah it's been awhile though. Correct me if I'm wrong, telescoping series are those that start with a fraction that doesn't cancel and end with one that doesn't, i.e, the middle/end cancels out. I just forget how to do that. It's been a few months since AP tests...

Comment: Try to write the summand as a difference of two sequences. Hint: If you know partial fraction decomposition, then that would be very helpful.

Comment: add $n$ and subtract $n$ to the numerator.

Comment: Oh yeah. Partial fractions work here. So, $\int (\cfrac{A}{n}+\cfrac{B}{n+1})dn = \int (\cfrac{1}{n}+\cfrac{-1}{n+1}) dn= ln(n)-\int (\cfrac{1}{n+1}) dn= ln(n)-ln(n+1)+C$. However, this is not the result that I was supposed to get.

Comment: Try $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+1}$. This will separate out the fraction into the sum of two fractions (hence partial fraction decomposition). Then, try writing out each term of the summation and find the pattern. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S = $\Sigma_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}$

$\text{Partial Fraction Decomposition:}$

$\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)} = \frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n+1}$

Multiply both sides by denominator of left side: $1 = A\left(n+1\right) + B\left(n\right)$

Plug in convenient value of n to isolate A: $n=0 \rightarrow A = 1$

Plug in convenient value of n to isolate B: $n=-1 \rightarrow B = -1$

$S = \Sigma_{n=1}^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$

$\text{Telescoping Series:}$

$S = \Sigma_{n=1}^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \left( 1-\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right) + \left( \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right) + ... \left( \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1+1}\right)$

Note how the "inner" terms cancel, just leaving the first term and the final term.

$S = 1 - \frac{1}{k+2} = \frac{k+1}{k+2}$